# Solve in terms of $b$: $\log_b (1 - 3x) = 3 + \log_b x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\log_b (1 - 3x) = 3 + \log_b x$$

If I use the properties of logs, I end up with

$$\log_b \left(\frac{1 - 3x}{x}\right) = 3$$

From there, the example I have says to exponentiate both sides, however, they use a $\log_2(\text{equation}) = 2$.  They then raise both sides to the $2$.  I can't seem to do this here, does someone have an example that better fits my situation?

Comment: Raise $b$ to the powers involved.  Note that $b^{\log_b(y)}=y$. So you should end up with $\frac{1-3x}{x}=b^3$.

Comment: I've got it solved, thanks.  If you answer this question with your comment, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: It seems what is really missing here is an understanding of logarithms:  Recall that $$\log_b(z) = y \quad\iff\quad b^y = z.$$  In other words, $\log_b(z)$ is the power to which you exponentiate $b$ to get $z$.  In your case, $$\log_b\left( \frac{1-3x}{x} \right) = 3 \quad\iff\quad b^3 = \frac{1-3x}{x}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, any $\log$ to the base $b$, such as $\log_b(y)$, is in its heart an *exponent*.  Let us start, then, from your expression
$$\log_b\left(\frac{1-3x}{x}\right)=3.$$
Raise $b$ to the powers we see on each side. We get
$$b^{\log_b\left(\frac{1-3x}{x}\right)}=b^3.$$
The left-hand side simplifies greatly. We get
$$\frac{1-3x}{x}=b^3.$$
The rest is elementary algebra. The above equation is (for $x\ne 0$) equivalent to
$$1-3x=b^3 x,$$
which is an easily solved linear equation.

**Comment:** There was no need to do the preliminary manipulation. We are told that 
$$\log_b(1-3x)=3+\log_b x.$$
Raise $b$ to the power on the left-hand side, the right-hand side. We obtain
$$b^{\log_b(1-3x)}=b^{3+\log_b x}.$$
By the "laws of logarithms" this yields
$$1-3x=b^3 x.$$